# offline NuGetPackages location visual studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I installed visual studio 2019 and I am looking for the default location of `NuGetPackages` . I found out that in previous version that location is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\`. I read [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-package-source-in-visual-studio-2015/).  But I could not see that location with VS 2019 installed. So, where is the default location for `NuGetPackages` in VS 2019 ? or am I missing something basic as I am new to VS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> %UserProfile%\.nuget\packages